# Is there a name for the code smell where we add different types of objects to a list or array instead of defining a new data structure?

Tags: code-smell

I came across a question earlier where someone asked how to create an array list with multiple object types ([Create an ArrayList with multiple object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types)).

The easiest solution is to create a list of objects, but many people mentioned in the replies and comments that using a list of objects is not a good idea, and might even be a code smell. The preferred solution by consensus seems to be a new class that takes in the different types as its parameters.

I can see why creating a list of objects would be problematic, as it's too easy to forget what order the objects are in, what type they are, etc.

I have seen this problem before in code that I've worked with, so I know it's a common blunder.

I was wondering if there is a name for it. Most code smells I've come across have a name, but I don't recall coming across one that described this one. I tried to look it up, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Having an array of `Object`s doesn't strike me as a code smell. *Downcasting* them does, and if you're doing anything with them that can't be done with a plain `Object` that's what you're going to have to do.

Comment: Code smells, in general, don't have names.  Anti-patterns do, but those are pretty vaporous as well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell both list multiple code smells by name. Conspicuously missing is the one I described in the above post, however...

Comment: @trentcl It's a lazy solution to a problem that can lead to problems further down the line. I think that qualifies it as a code smell. It seems especially problematic in a strongly-typed language like Java, since generalizing more specific entities to objects means we're discarding useful type hints.

Comment: Does it need a name? "A code smell by any other name smells just as bad."

Comment: @Calculemus - The problem (if it is a problem) is probably much more common in a weakly typed or dynamically typed language. In javascript, perl, python, ruby, and other loosely typed languages, it's easy to create an array or list in which elements have different types. No down casting is needed to create a list than contains "42" and 42 because these languages don't have a concept of a type-specific list.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a problem and qualifies as a code smell. Think of JSON, XML, YAML, ... The whole point of these representations is that they are very generic and can handle multiple types in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Source Making is just a website.  There are things on there that I wouldn't even characterize as smells.  The point is that there doesn't exist an exhaustive categorization of everything that can happen to you as a software developer.  Sometimes (often) you just have to use some common sense and a bit of intestinal fortitude, and make up your own mind about what you should or shouldn't do.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Stackexchange is just a website too. And you are just a StackExchange commenter. By the way, Source Making is used as a reference by a Software Engineering course at the University of Toronto (CSC207), which perhaps might lend it at least some semblance of authority to people who don't bother reading its excellent content.

Comment: @DavidHammen It's much easier to talk about specific code smells (and blunders and errors in general) if we have a name for them. Imagine if we had no names, or no language, for anything.

Comment: @Calculemus - Look at the list of code smells in the links that you yourself provided. One of the is the "lazy class / freeloader" code smell. This happens oftentimes in statically typed languages, where a freeloader class is created for the sole intent of returning a collection of values of disparate types from a function. There is no need for this in a more free-form language such as javascript or python. The code smell of that freeloader class can be eliminated by returning a well-documented tuple or dictionary. What you are seeing as a problem is what many see as a positive.

Comment: Like **every** computer programming construct / concept, this construct (an array or tuple of disparate types) can be abused / misused. But just because it can be abused does not mean it is a problem. A function with a cyclomatic complexity greater than forty is an extreme abuse of conditional and/or loop statements. (Such functions do exist, without a single `goto`.) But that does not mean that every conditional, every loop is a code smell.

Comment: `And you are just a StackExchange commenter.` -- Quite right.  Don't trust anything some random stranger has told you on the Internet without verifying it yourself.

Comment: `And you are just a StackExchange commenter.` Riiight. I strongly suggest that you look at @RobertHarvey's rating at this site and at StackOverflow. On a good day, I *might* qualify as "just another StackExchange commenter". Robert Harvey is in a very different class and is well beyond the "just a StackExchange commenter" stage. Just in case the message is not getting across, this is an extreme complement to Robert. He is not "just a StackExchange commenter." You should pay attention to what he wrote.

Comment: @DavidHammen I just turned his own rhetorical style against him. He was the one who claimed "it's just a website". That is a really poor argument, and I wanted to show it by mimicking it. Websites can be reputable, or not. The fact that it is a website says nothing about its reputability or its contents. Furthermore, you just engaged in a really obvious appeal to authority, and nobody with half a brain would be susceptible to such a thing. I don't care about his reputation on this website, or yours. I care about the soundness of people's arguments.

Answer (score 5):

I think the situation you described is a special case of a more general phenomenon I have seen several times: abusing some loosely typed container for creating and managing data records which actually deserve an abstraction on their own. This does not always come along in form of a list of `object`s, but also in form of dictionaries, string lists, tuples and sometimes just pairs or triples of variables which are passed around together from one method to another.

To clean up such mess, one has to introduce a type or class, give it an appropriate name, then introduce some member variables, give them appropriate names, too, and then think about further steps like moving parts of the code into methods of that newly created class. I guess finding a good name is often what stops people from doing this at first place, [naming things well is one of hardest problems in Computer science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

Is there a specific, broadly accepted name for this kind of "code smell"? I honestly don't know, I would probably call it a **"missing abstraction"**. However, the different refactorings for cleaning up such code have names in [Fowler's refactoring catalog](https://refactoring.com/catalog/). The most suitable ones for fighting the described phenomenon (like "Extract class" or "Encapsulate Record", or "Combine Functions into Class") are listed in the [encapsulation section](https://refactoring.com/catalog/?filter=tags-encapsulation) of that catalog. In the long run, I guess the names of these ways to improve code will probably be more useful than any names for "bad" code.

Comment: In the spirit of some of our previous discussions, I held off on casting a close vote to see how this question would play out.  Alas, the result has been predictably disappointing, and I've decided to cast the final close vote.  The problem, of course, is that visitors should be asking about their particular issue, concern or topic, and not using the site as a proxy for Google search.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I actually spent about an hour before creating this question combing through Google search results and found nothing relevant. So I did not use the site as a proxy for Google search, because Google isn't currently smart enough to offer a good answer to my question. The answers here turned out to be helpful for me, regardless of how disappointing they may have been to you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree that "name that thing" question are mostly not very interesting or enlightning, and this one is probably no exception. That does not mean, however, that this specific question cannot be answered in a sensible way. Of course, I took the freedom to interpret the question not too literally, but in the sense of *"is the described observation part of a bigger picture"*. Should the question be closed? Well, five people voted for closing it, I am fine with that. Should it be deleted? ...

Comment: ... I don't think so, the question and its answers seem to have a value for some readers, not just for the OP. Not every question & answer asked on this site is "worth for nomination of the question of the month", that's true, but IMHO that does not mean we should only accept questions which fall into such a category.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be a code smell but it might lead to code smells.

If we think of an array as construct that groups items together, books[] or movies[] being simple examples, then is there anything common about the objects and why they are stored in the same array or group? As mentioned by other it might indicate a common interface. IReadable or IWatchable.

Answer (score 1):

The name is lack of **type safety**. You toss in a bunch of objects and leave it up to the consumer of the objects to figure out what they really are and cast them back to their subtypes. Which can go wrong at runtime. You would rather have some verification at compile time.

It is not necessarily bad to have different types in the same collection but you would expect some interface or common base type (with polymorphism) to go with it so they can be treated as one type.